# PyMongo checking if entry is already in array

Tags: pymongo

I want to have an array of IPs that went to `x` webpage and have them in an array. However right now everytime an IP connects it gets added, if multiple people connect multiple times there'll be many duplicates.

Currently I'm just using

```py
query = {"_id": paste_id, "ip": {"$ne": real_ip}
collection.update_one(query, {"$push": {"ip": ip}})
```

but that (logically) just pushes the entry into the array, what'd be a way to check if `ip` is already in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER

The updated code you posted is checking for `real_ip` and then inserting `ip`; so you're not checking the item your actually updating.

My original answer below still stands as the correct approach; however this complete example demonstrates attempting to insert the `real_ip` 5 times and it shows the value is only inserted once:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

collection = MongoClient()['mydatabase'].collection

result = collection.insert_one({'ip': []})
paste_id = result.inserted_id

real_ip = '1.2.3.4'

for i in range(5):
    query = {"_id": paste_id, "ip": {"$ne": real_ip}}
    collection.update_one(query, {"$push": {"ip": real_ip}})

print(list(collection.find()))
```

prints:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5feefdb862e2ed3ea952a035'), 'ip': ['1.2.3.4']}]
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER

Add a check that the IP is not already in the `ip` array, e.g.

```
query = {'ip': {'$ne': ip}}
```

Comment: But this will update every document in the collection where `ip` isn't equal to their IP.

Comment: Add it to whatever query you already creating.

Comment: I changed my query to be `{"_id": paste_id, "ip": {"$ne": real_ip}}` but it did not work and I am still getting duplicated

Comment: Please update your question to meet https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example